# Reacjs How to return selected row in datagrid

Tags: reactjs, listview, datagrid, arrow-functions

I'm working on a search component that is a button that, when pressed, opens a drawer with a datagrid. Then I need to choose a row from that datagrid and return its id to the form.
But i can not do it.
Here my code
/// Component  ProBusqueda (Datagrid into the Drawer)

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Datagrid} from 'react-admin';
import keyBy from 'lodash/keyBy';

export const ProBusqueda = (props) => {
    const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
    const [StateData, setStateData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        dataProvider.getList(
            'DetailPro',
            .then(({data}) => {
                setStateData(data);
            })  }, []);

//// This function doest work
    const GetIdSelected = ({record}) => {
        return record.id
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{margin: '1em'}}>
                <Datagrid
                    data={keyBy(StateData, 'id')}
                    ids={StateData.map(({id}) => id)}
                >
                    <button onClick={() => props.callback(GetIdSelected(*argument?*))}>Select Row</button>  
                    <TextField label="id" source="id"/>
                    <TextField label="Razon social" source="raz"/>
                </Datagrid>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
export default ProBusqueda;
```

Thanks

Comment: `GetIdSelected` appears to expect to be passed an object that contains a `record` object to access your id. You are passing it 0 arguments.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem. I don´t know how to pass the argument to then return de value. Thanks